# Qt C++ downloading a XML file and showing it in textEdit

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have a problem with downloading a XML file from server. There's some code:

```
QByteArray data;
...
void DownloadXML::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
     QUrl address = "abc.com/file.xml"

     QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
     connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
     this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

     QNetworkRequest request;
     request.setUrl(address); 
     manager->get(request);

     ui->textEdit->insertPlainText(QString::fromAscii(data));
}
```

And replyFinished slot:

```
void DownloadXML::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply){
    reply->deleteLater();
    data = reply->readAll();
}
```

My problem is: when i click button first time, xml file doesn't show up in textEdit, but when i click button second time, xml file shows up normally. How i can fix that? I think that i must wait in program for downloaded data, but i don't know how to do that.

Btw. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `ui->textEdit->insertPlainText(QString::fromAscii(data));` gets called before the manager's finished signal is emitted. Remove that line and

Change your slot to this:

```
void DownloadXML::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply){
    reply->deleteLater();
    data = reply->readAll();
    ui->textEdit->insertPlainText(QString::fromAscii(data));
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a `QEventLoop` to wait until the signal gets called.

```
void DownloadXML::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
     QUrl address = "abc.com/file.xml"

     QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

     QNetworkRequest request;
     request.setUrl(address); 
     QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);

     QEventLoop loop;
     connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
     loop.exec();

     if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
     {
         //No Error
         reply->deleteLater();
         data = reply->readAll();
         ui->textEdit->insertPlainText(QString::fromAscii(data));
     }
     loop.quit();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the `on_pushButton_clicked()` ? I want to do something with this XML file.

Comment: @Seba Sure, see my edit. No longer requires any slots. I use this exact setup on many of my projects.

Comment: Oh thats it. Thank you very much for your help!